# How to calculate value with code for specific formule in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Oracle SQL query.
In results I get something like that:

```
CODE || VALUE
I || 10
II || 30
III || 50
IV || -20
V || 60
VII || -45
VIII || 0
IX || 100
X || 0
```

Next I want for CODE = X create formule like:

CASE 1:

```
SUM OF I,II,III,IV,V,IX
```

CASE 2:

```
I+II+III-IV-V+IX
```

How can I implent these formule in sql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      select sum(value) from table where code not like 'VI%'   
      Union
      select sum(case when code in ('IV', 'V' ) then -value
      else value end case) from table where code not like 
        'VI%'
```

> Just a different way of doing the same as above via union

Answer (score 1):

You would use aggregation:

```
select sum(case when code in ('I', 'II', 'III', 'IV', 'V', 'IX') then value else 0 end) as case1,
       sum(case when code in ('I', 'II', 'III', 'IX') then value
                when code in ('IV', 'V') then -value
                else 0
           end) as case2
from t;
```